# Is Perl module Test::Simple needed?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I don't get it. There is a great module [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMore) witch is part of Perl distribution. But sometimes in some Perl modules there are links to the module [Test::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aSimple).

Test::Simple is not part of the Perl distribution so to install some modules that need Test::Simple you should install Test::Simple first.

Are there any reasons why to use Test::Simple instead of Test::More?

PS for example, Test::Simple dependency is written in file https://metacpan.org/source/MMIMS/Net-Twitter-4.00007/META.yml

Comment: Note that Test::More and Test::Simple are both part of the same distribution (Test-Simple), and it's included in Perl as whole.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you! This is the thing that I didn't know. This question has appeared because of my notunderstanding. =)

Answer (score 8):

[Test::Simple](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Simple.html) is part of the Core distribution, so there is no need to install it:

```
corelist Test::Simple

Test::Simple was first released with perl v5.6.2
```

Here is a quote from the POD:

> This module is by no means trying to be a complete testing system.
>   It's just to get you started. Once you're off the ground its
>   recommended you look at Test::More.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood my mistake. I have Test::Simple 0.92 installded on my ubuntu 10.04, but the module Net::Twitter needs 0.98. Thats why I got the message that I need to install that module.

Comment: Same thing would have happened if Net::Twitter used Test::More. The only difference is that it say Test::More in the error message instead of Test::Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Test::Simple module is from the core module, so you do not have to install it.
Here is the url of use this module in the document, and you can also see that it is from the core module.
[The official document of Test::Simple Module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Simple.html)